# Use case for np.log2 vs math.log2

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, conventions

Sometimes, authors use [`np.log2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html) instead of [`math.log2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2). For example, in [this PyTorch code](https://github.com/eladrich/pixel2style2pixel/blob/5cfff385beb7b95fbce775662b48fcc80081928d/models/encoders/psp_encoders.py#L16):

```py
num_pools = int(np.log2(spatial))
```

(where `spatial` is a Python number)

Because [`math.log2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2) is <strike>a built-in</strike> an included battery, I don't see a reason for calling [`np.log2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html) instead - is it maybe to follow convention, or because [`np.log2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html) is thought to be faster?

Comment: Some people use that in cases where a function might be given either a scalar or a numpy array.  Remember that `math.log2` can't handle an array.  `np.log2` can handle both.  Also remember that there is no reason that `math.log2` should be faster than `np.log2`.  Neither are "built-in" -- they're both imported modules.

Comment: @TimRoberts `math` is a built-in module so I think it's fair to call `math.log2` a built-in when comparing with a third-party module.

Comment: @TimRoberts It has, `math.log2` mainly serves built-in numeric types, while `np.log2` mainly serves array type and is a ufunc, requiring consideration of more complex situations than `math.log2` (argument parsing alone is much more complex). When the argument is a built-in `float` type number, `math.log2` is more than 6 times faster than `np.log2` on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If we have numpy arrays, then `np.log2` should be used because it works on arrays while `math.log2` does not. If we have a scalar, `math.log2` is faster and therefore preferred. As for why people use `np.log2` for scalars, I can only speculate. It's most likely because they already have it imported and don't care about the minor speed improvement gained by using `math.log2`.

Comment: `int()` will probably raise when passed an array, won't it? And is it a fact that `math.log2` is faster (for numpy scalars)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні, it's easy to show with `timeit` that `np` functions are about 5x slower than the corresponding `math` call for a single number (python or numpy scalar), i.e. 2.5 us vs 500 ns.  The difference has more to do with calling overhead than with the calculation itself (compiled c code).

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні The question seems to specifically be about operating on scalars (since `math.log2` doesn't work on arrays so numpy would be on the only choice between the two), so I don't think it is relevant whether `int` can be applied to an array result.